# How to write the next sentence in the same line of the previous user's input

Tags: java

I use NetBeans IDE 8.2 and I wrote this code:

```
System.out.print("Hello, my name is ");    
Name=scan.nextLine();    
System.out.print("and I am ");    
age=scan.nextInt();    
Name=scan.nextLine();    
System.out.print("years old. ");    
System.out.print("I'm enjoying my time at ");    
Name=scan.nextLine();    
System.out.print("though I miss my pet ");    
Name=scan.nextLine();    
System.out.print("Very much!");
```

**The output is:**

> Hello, my name is (Input)
>
> and I am (input)
>
> years old. I'm enjoying my time at (input)
>
> though I miss my pet (input)
>
> Very much!

**But I want it to be:**

> Hello, my name is (input) and I am (input) years
>
> old. I'm enjoying my time at (input), though
>
> I miss my pet (input) very much!

I have no idea how to make the each sentence appear in the same line as the inputs...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Might not be possible since you need to press _return_ to send the input to the console. That _return_ also means a new line.

Answer (score 1):

Gather the inputs separately from when you print them out.  You can make use of [Java's String formatting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/formatting.html) (the tokens you care about are `%s` and `%d`) to achieve this.

Essentially...

```
System.out.printf("Hello, my name is %s and I am %d years old. ...", name, age, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the fact of using Eclipse IDE is misleading you. When you run an application on the Eclipse Terminal, the `stdin` and the `stdout` are printed in the same Console. However, the information that you enter on the `stdin` is not written on the `stdout`. Moreover, since you need to process the all line on the scanner, you will require an end of line on the user input so you cannot keep the sentence as it goes. Notice that although you could see the sentence on a single line, you will not be storing the information since Eclipse mixes both `stdin` and `stdout` (should have different colors though).

My suggestion is to divide the code in two sections:

- The first one to ask the user the required information
- The second one to print the retrieved information and construct the message you want.

Here I provide you the code based on your solution:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String name = null;
    int age = 0;
    String place = null;
    String petName = null;
    try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        System.out.println("Please enter your name");
        name = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter your age");
        age = scan.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Please enter where you are");
        place = scan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter your pet name");
        petName = scan.nextLine();
    }

    System.out.print("Hello, my name is ");
    System.out.print(name);
    System.out.print(" and I am ");
    System.out.print(age);
    System.out.println(" years old. ");

    System.out.print("I'm enjoying my time at ");
    System.out.print(place);
    System.out.print("though I miss my pet ");
    System.out.print(petName);
    System.out.println(" very much!");
}
```

Notice that:

- The try with resources command is used to close the scanner at the end of the execution
- All the information is retrieved on the first block
- On the second block you can change any `print` by `println` to force the new lines you wish.